# CodenameOne MapContainer Zoom Level

Tags: codenameone

I am using the MapContainer(cn1lib). so in android devices low relsolution the zoom works fine. But in android devices high resolution the zoom not works fine. The zoom in stay far. i attach a screen with the to max zoom in, it is a bug or i'm wrong?

[SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e7yty.png)

[GUI-DESIGN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RtLf6.png)

public class StateMachine extends StateMachineBase {

```
MapContainer mapContainer;

public StateMachine(String resFile) {
    super(resFile);
    // do not modify, write code in initVars and initialize class members there,
    // the constructor might be invoked too late due to race conditions that might occur
}

/**
 * this method should be used to initialize variables instead of the
 * constructor/class scope to avoid race conditions
 */
protected void initVars(Resources res) {
}

@Override
protected void beforeShow(Form f) {
    try {

        this.mapContainer.setShowMyLocation(true);
        this.mapContainer.zoom(new Coord(20.640086, -103.432207), 17);
        this.mapContainer.setCameraPosition(new Coord(20.640086, -103.432207));
        this.mapContainer.addMarker(
                EncodedImage.createFromImage(fetchResourceFile().getImage("pin.png"), false),
                new Coord(20.640086, -103.432207),
                "Hi marker", "Optional long description",
                new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                        Dialog.show("Marker Clicked!", "You clicked the marker", "OK", null);
                    }
                }
        );


        this.mapContainer.addPointerDraggedListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                mapContainer.clearMapLayers();
                mapContainer.addMarker(EncodedImage.createFromImage(fetchResourceFile().getImage("pin.png"), false), mapContainer.getCameraPosition(), "Hi marker", "Optional long description", new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                        Dialog.show("Marker Clicked!", "You clicked the marker", "OK", null);
                    }
                });

            }
        });

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    super.beforeShow(f); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}

@Override
protected Component createComponentInstance(String componentType, Class cls) {
    if (cls == MapComponent.class) {    
        this.mapContainer = new MapContainer();
        return this.mapContainer;
    }
    return super.createComponentInstance(componentType, cls); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}
```

}

Comment: Please post some code so we can help you better.

Comment: I've updated the post, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a `MapComponent` not a native map, so it uses the old open street maps support and relatively simple map rendering even on the device. We have support for [native google maps](http://github.com/codenameone/codenameone-google-maps/) which isn't exposed in the GUI builder but you can add it thru code.

This will embed the actual native GUI into place which will both look and feel better on the device although it will look the same on the simulator.